# Tema que é usado na landing do Atom IDE

Tags: ide, editor-de-texto, atom, temas

Como o pessoal do suporte do Atom demora muito a responder, gostaria de saber se a comunidade @Stackoverflow sabe o tema que é usado na landing page do Atom IDE?

https://ide.atom.io/

[image: Tema do atom IDE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifiquei diretamente no Forum da aplicação, e infelizmente o dono do tema não trabalha mais na empresa. A empresa aguarda anciosamente pelo retorno, e logo depois disso, por projetos como este tema, em ação.

Answer (score 1):

Existe um thema criado com as mesmas definições de cores da demonstração do site da Atom, ele foi criado por um desenvolvedor que tambem gostou das definições de cores porem nao consegui encontrar porque o autor principal não trabalhava mais na Atom.

O nome deste thema é "atom-ide-dark-syntax" ele está disponível no link: https://atom.io/themes/atom-ide-dark-syntax, para instalar clique no botão Install dentro da pagina do link anterior.

Depois de instalado o Thema, na IDE Atom vá em **Settings** depois clique em **Themes**. Na caixa de seleção **"UI Theme"** escolha **"Atom Dark"** e em **"Sintax Theme"** escolha "Atom Ide Dark".